# Extending postgres image using dockerfile with POSTGRES_PASSWORD

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm extending the postgres image with an argument POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres so that my derived container would already have a default password using docker build with dockerfile.

Whenever I ran `psql -U postgres` on the container from the derived image i made from postgres, I get:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

On my DockerFile I have:

```
ARG POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
FROM postgres:alpine

RUN apk add --update nodejs
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN apk add --update erlang
RUN apk add --update elixir

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

then I ran

```sh
docker build -t myImage .
docker run --name sample -d -it myImage
docker exec -it sample bash
```

I want to run `psql -U postgres` on `sample` container (image extended from postgres).

Comment: This seems like you're looking for an orchestration system like Docker Compose, more than trying to fix these things in a Dockerfile.  The `CMD` setting to run a shell instead of starting the database would be the immediate cause of your error.

Comment: @DavidMaze Making an image with elixir and postgres running is not possible? Should I use docker compose to connect postgres image and elixir image?

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely run your database and applications in separate containers.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `ARG POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres` by `ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres`

The postgres docker image documentation state that this parameter is an Environement Variable, so this might help.